# HTML CSS Mysterious Bottom Border

Tags: html, css, html-table

I was building some tables and went through a lot of iterations. At some point I picked up this weird bottom border on my first row (https://jujusupply.com/pages/customer-gift-notes) and I'm not sure where it's coming from or how to get rid of it? It's just a very simple HTML table.

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}
td {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: em(14px);
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 12px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border: 8px solid white;
    height: 200px;
}
td:hover {
    background-color: #ffde17;
}
```

```html
    <div style="overflow-x: auto;">
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's from here :

```
media="all"
tr:first-child th:after, tr:first-child td:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -15px;
    right: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1c1d1d;
}
```

in the `theme.scss.css` file

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it